Formula for bump function
I would like to formulate a bump function (link) $f:\Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ with the following properties on the reals:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le -1 \\
1,  & \mbox{if } x = 0 \\
0, & \mbox{if } x \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$
In addition (because it's a bump function), it should be smooth and continuously differentiable, and the first-order derivative at $x = -1$ and $x = 1$ should be zero.
But one last stipulation defeats me. I would like it to be the case that
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = 1
$$
The example of a bump function offered in the Wikipedia article linked above comes close (I have added $1$ to the exponent to take it to a value of $1$ at $x = 0$):
$$
g(x) :=
\begin{cases} 
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le -1 \\
\exp^{1-\frac{1}{1-x^2}},  & \mbox{if } -1 < x < 1 \\
0, & \mbox{if } x \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$

The function $g$ answers all my requirements except $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = 1$. And here I hit a wall. I assume that, in principle, one could multiply $x$ by some factor $a > 1$ to obtain the precise result required... But that would require having a formula for the antiderivative $\int \exp^{1-\frac{1}{1-ax^2}} dx$, and I have no idea whatsoever how to find it. The usual techniques don't seem to apply. Furthermore, Mathematica just shrugs - which suggests to me that I could spend a very long time trying and make no progress at all.
So:

Is $g(x)$ in fact integrable (in the sense of producing a formula for the antiderivative)? If so, how?
If not, then is there a completely different formula that would satisfy the conditions set out for $f$? I really don't know how to begin constructing such a thing since my math knowledge of the properties of various classes of functions simply isn't up the task.

UPDATE AFTER SUGGESTION IN COMMENTS
I have looked at the answer here (many thanks @Lorago, I searched for "bump function" here but this didn't come up for me), but cannot make it work. Perhaps I am doing something wrong? As per the answer there, set
$$
f_0(x) :=
\begin{cases} 
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},  & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
I can see that the function $f_1(x) := -e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} + 1$ would produce a positive bump with $f_1(0) = 1$; though since $f_1(x) \rightarrow 0$ only as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, I am not sure of the utility of it. The choice of a piecewise cut-off at $x = 0$ for $f_1 (x)$ also seems odd.
However, let's go with it. The next step in the answer is to set
$$
g_0(x)=f\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)
$$
So,
$$
g_0(x) :=
\begin{cases} 
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{(x - \frac {1}{2})^2}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{(\frac {1}{2} - x)^2}},  & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
The linked answer states "This is a smooth bump function centred at the origin, but $g_0(0)\neq1$." But I beg to differ; here's a plot:

Clearly, I have deeply misunderstood what is being suggested. But for the sake of completeness, now set $g_1(x)=\frac{g_0(x)}{g_0(0)}$. Mathematica makes the following simplification:
$$
\frac {e^{-\frac{1}{(x - \frac {1}{2})^2}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{(\frac {1}{2} - x)^2}}}{e^{-\frac{1}{(- \frac {1}{2})^2}} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{(\frac {1}{2})^2}}} = e^{-\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right)^2}+8}
$$
So, we now have
$$
g_1(x) :=
\begin{cases} 
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \\
e^{-\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{2} - x\right)^2}+8},  & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$$
This is proposed as the solution. But it looks like this...

Even allowing for the fact that one might have made adjustments to $f_0$ to produce something more like $f_1$ with appropriate piecewise cut-offs, it's easy to see that I am doing something deeply wrong.
For completeness, here is a plot of the same process applied to $f_1$, with appropriate adjustments to the cut-off points for the piecewise specification. It's marginally closer but still does not address most of the requirements:

Sadly, despite the previous answer, I find myself still in need of assistance.

Hi @Lorago. I have read the answer you link to (it didn't come up in my searches, weird). I'm afraid it leaves me more baffled than ever. It's fairly obvious that I must have failed to grasp something pretty fundamental about the answer there; if it works for other people, then it must be me that's missing something. So, my question is now updated to account for this.

If you don't require the function to be infinitely differentiable then you can use easier functions than $e^{-1/x^2},$ for example $\cos^2 x.$

Your written out version of $g_0$ is not correct, and furthermore there appears to be a typo in the linked question. I believe the function should be $g_0(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)$. If we write $f(x)=e^{-\frac1{x^2}}\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$, then$$g_0(x)=e^{-\frac4{\left(2x+1\right)^2}-\frac{4}{\left(2x-1\right)^2}}\chi_{\left(-\frac1{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)}(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{4}{\left(2x+1\right)^2}-\frac{4}{\left(2x-1\right)^2}},&x\in\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right),\
0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Thanks for this. I'm still confused, sorry. First, let's accept $
f_0(x) :=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},  & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$ and $g_0(x)=f\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)$. Surely, this gives us  $f_0(x) :=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \mbox{if } x \le 0 \
e^{-\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}+x)^2}-\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2}-x)^2}} ,  & \mbox{if } x > 0
\end{cases}
$ rather than your result? Your formula does produce a bump. But it is approx $0.00033$ in amplitude and I can't integrate it; though the integral is definitely $<<1$...

(I am really grateful for your input, though)

Error in my comment above: should read "Surely this gives us $g_0(x):=$... rather than $f_0$.

"Explicit" (in elementary terms) integrals of bump/test functions are usually unavailable... But existence of a normalizing constant is often assured by the intermediate value theorem.

@Lorago "...there appears to be a typo in the linked question." FYI, I fixed the typo.

What does "smooth and continuously differentiable" mean? To most of us, "smooth" means $C^\infty$ (continuous derivatives of all orders). If you mean just $C^1$ (continuously differentiable), then omit the word smooth. The usual bump function construction achieves smooth, but as various answers to your questions show, $C^1$ is far easier.

If you want to check alternatives consider visiting this post

Should the direction of this close as duplicate be in the other direction, or is this perhaps a good candidate for merging?

@M.Winter I don't understood your edit by making explicit the function should be from reals to reals?... differentiable complex-valued function are analytic, so described entirely by a power series, and non-piecewise defined power series cannot be compact supported or it will violate the Identity Theorem: so there are not complex-differentiable function on $C_c^\infty$, so Why bother to pinpoint it should be real-valued when is the only possible alternative to have?

@Joako My edits had a far less sophisticated intent. You wrote "a bump function $f(x)$", but strictly speaking $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ for the input $x$, so a real value, not a function. I first changed it to $f$, and later to $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, but I don't insist (though I believe it's better to be explicit).

@M.Winter sorry if it sound like whining, it was real curiosity in order to see if I was missing something: the argument I gave is based on things I self-taught myself here in MSE, so I thought that maybe there were something I had misunderstood.

@Joako Don't worry, I should have explained my edit in the first place :)

I have a stricter version than what is being asked for. I have had a very similar question in the past nag at me but never figured it out. What I had been interested in was more restrictive than OP asked for. Since these types of questions about the nature of bump functions are fairly common, I have some of my thought process described at the bottom as I worked through the list of properties I wanted my solution to have.
I have a smooth bump function $f$ that has the properties:

$f$ is even,
$f\ge 0$ for all $x$,
$f \equiv 0$ on outside of $(-1,1)$,
$0 < f \le 1$ on $(-1,1)$,
$f(0) = 1$,
$f$ is decreasing away from $0$, and
$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx = 1$.

The hard part, as OP correctly identified, is making $f(0) = 1$ work with the integral being $1$. You can shrink the support of the function to obtain the desired value for the integral, but you might lose $f(0) = 1$ in the process. Or if you shrink the support and keep $f(0) = 1$, you might lose the desired value for the integral.  You can add smaller bump functions supported away from $0$ after shrinking the support of the function which can work if you are careful, however your solution might not decay monotonically away from $0$.
Let $\displaystyle f_0(x) = e^{1-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}\chi_{(-1,1)}(x)$ be the standard bump function. Let $\displaystyle J = \int_{-1}^1 f_0(x)\,dx$. By this MSE post, $\displaystyle J = e^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg(K_1\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg) - K_0\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\bigg)\approx 1.2069$, where $K_{\nu}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind. Define the candidate bump function $f$ by
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}(f_0(2x) + \alpha f_0(x)), $$
where $\displaystyle \alpha = \frac{\frac{1}{J}-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{J}}$.
It is easy to see that $f$ is nonnegative and identically $0$ outside of $(-1,1)$. Since it is a convex combination of rescalings of $f_0$ and $0 \le f_0 \le 1$, we also have $0 \le f \le 1$. Likewise, $f(0) = 1$ and $f$ is decreasing away from $0$ since $f_0$ is. The tricky part is evaluating the integral of $f_0$ (which can be found in the linked MSE post), but after that, it is a simple manipulation to show that $f$ has integral $1$.
Here's a look into the thought process I had to come up with this. As for why I picked $f$ the way I did: I wanted to start with $f_0$ as it is the most common example of a bump function and OP had identified it specifically. I shrunk its support ($f_0(2x)$) to $\big(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big)$ because its integral is larger than $1$. I at first added a couple of bump functions based on shifts and rescalings of $f_0$ symmetric with respect to the origin peaked near $\pm \frac{1}{2}$, but it quickly got to be difficult to manage the monotone decreasing part without getting really into the weeds. The problem was that the smaller bump functions I wanted to add had a peak and then decayed right around the edge of the support of $f_0(2x)$, so I realized that what I really wanted was a function that was flat but nonzero through the support of $f_0(2x)$, leading to using a rescaled version of $f_0(x)$. The rest was just doing a specific convex combination to make the integral and $f(0) = 1$ conditions work together.
Here is a Desmos demonstration for the function. And here is a graph demonstrating the function:


It is your solution class $C_c^\infty$? from what I see in the answer looks like it is, but playing in Desmos looks like its derivatives explodes to $\pm \infty$ near $x=\pm 1/2$ as I keep taking derivatives (maybe is just a visual effect, but got me wonder if its indeed infinitely smooth).

It is because it's just the sum of two smooth functions.

The finite sum of class $C_c^\infty$ functions is still in $C_c^\infty$, right? This is how you now it is still smooth?

That is exactly correct.

Consider the following function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad x\leq -1;\\
0,\quad x\geq 1;\\
1,\quad x=0;\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\quad\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$
this is a smooth bump function from the family of Non-analytic smooth functions that is continuous in every point as are their derivatives, fulfills $f(-1)=f(1)=0$, $f(0)=1$, and $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\ dx = 1$ at least in Wolfram-Alpha, so also $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx = 1$, and also is a flat function at the top so have the pretty nonlinear bump function looks which is pretty similar to another example that suits your requests, the Rvachëv function $R(x)$, which is a displaced version of the first lobe of the famous Fabius function, example of an infinitely differentiable function that is nowhere analytic: you can check in this answer it fulfills your integral requirement, but it has no closed-form: in this answer a numerical approximation is shown, also it solves the Delay differential equation $R'(x) = 2R(2x+1)-2R(2x-1)$ (a good reference source for this function are the papers from Juan Arias de Reyna, year 2017).
You can check the plot of $f(x)$ in Desmos.


Added later
Later I realized after the comment of @10762409 that for any real valued $k$ the function:
$$f(x,k) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad x\leq -1;\\
0,\quad x\geq 1;\\
1,\quad x=0;\\
\dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{k(1-2|x|)}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\quad\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$
split the interval $[-1,\ 1]$ such as  $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,k)\ dx = 1$, but it keeps making nice bump functions only when $k>1$, becoming a smooth approximation of the Rectangular function $\Pi(x)$ as $k\to \infty$, as could be seen in Desmos. Also, but this need to be verified, the bump function get straight-line-edges near $k\sim \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The OPs requirements are fulfilled for $k>0$.

Update
I was able to informally validate that the slopes of $f(x,k)$ becomes locally* straight lines at $k=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$: playing in Desmos I realize that the edges going straight lines means the 2nd derivative $f_{xx}$ should get flat near these points, which happens only when $k$ is such as the 3rd derivative $f_{xxx}$ becomes zero at the point $x=1/2$, so evaluating $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}f(x,k)\Biggr|_{x=1/2}=16k(4k^2-3)=0$ which leads to $k^*=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, where the function matches at $x=1/2$ a straight line with slope $\sqrt{3}$.
(*): the function $f_x(x,\sqrt{3}/2)$ is not perfectly a flat function where it should be a straight line so is not $100\%$ accurate. In this sense, the Rvachëv function do behave accurately as straight-lines edges as you could see from the presented equation.
Desmos


Last Update
I was able to make a bump function with true straight-line slopes, unfortunately not in closed form but simple enough to work with it:
$$q(x)=\int\limits_{-1}^{x}u(y)dy$$
and its argument is given by the function:
$$u(x) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad |x|\geq 1\\
0,\quad x= 0\\
2,\quad x=-\frac12\\
-2,\quad x=\frac12\\
\dfrac{-2\,\text{sgn}(x)}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2||2x|-1|}{(|2x|-1)^2-||2x|-1|}\right)},\quad\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I compared in Desmos $q(x)$ with an approximation of the Rvachëv function and they look really close, but they are not the same function.
Careful that since the piecewise definition of $u(x)$ I am not sure if $q(x)$ smooth $C_c^\infty$ this time (but I believe it is), but as example it clarifies why the function $f\left(x,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$ is not perfectly matching straight-line slopes, their derivative at the points $|x|=\frac12$ don't have flat top.

By the way, if $u(x)$ is really $C_c^\infty$, then is highly probable that $q(x)$ is also fulfilling the question requirements as a valid answer (I checked in Desmos and kind of fit numerically), but the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} q(x)dx$ should be demonstrated first (but following the comment by @10762409 it should fit).
Also, as before you could make a family of solutions $q(x,k)$ using
$$u(x,k)\sim \dfrac{-2\,\text{sgn}(x)}{1+\exp\left(\frac{k(1-2||2x|-1|)}{(|2x|-1)^2-||2x|-1|}\right)}$$ which shows similar behavior than $f(x,k)$ but with true straight-line slopes.

You can show $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) = 1$ by symmetry. Looking at the graph suggests that the left half of the graph $(x < 0)$ can be rotated and shifted into $1 - f(x)$ on the right half of the graph. Indeed, a bit of algebra shows that for $p < 0.5$, $f(0.5 + p) + f(0.5 - p) = 0$; this can be formalized into a proof that the integral is 1 using the fact that $f$ is even.

@10762409 $$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)\ dx = \int_{-1}^{0}f(x)\ dx \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx $$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}(1-f(x))\ dx +\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx $$ $$=\int_{0}^{1}(1-f(x)+f(x)\ dx =  \int_{0}^{1}1\ dx=x|_0^1=1-0=1 $$ Is this how you think it could be used to prove its integral is unitary?

@Joako split the integral into two pieces like you did, then substitute $x=u-1$ to replace the first piece $\int_{-1}^{0} f(x) dx$ by $\int_{0}^{1} f(u-1) du$. By evenness, this is equal to $\int_{0}^{1} f(1-u) du$. Now recombine the integrals and use the identity $f(x) +f(1-x)=1$.

If you only require the first order derivative to be continuous, then you can take
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\cos^2\frac{\pi x}{2}&\text{when $-1\leq x\leq 1$}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It satisfies $f(x)=0$ when $|x|>1$, $f(0)=1,$ $f\in C^1(\mathbb R),$ and $\int f(x)\,dx=1.$

Hi @md2perpe, thanks for this, but would very much like it to be continuously differentiable...

Hmm. I think I may be mixing up "continuously" and "infinitely"... In which case, you are correct, @md2perpe

I really appreciate your answer,@md2perpe. I have to mark the other as correct because it is comprehensive. But your answer has also proved really useful and I have upvoted it. Thank you.

@RichardBurke-Ward. No problem. The best answer should get the big credit. And my answer can be useful for others who look for a simple bump function.

I have had the problem when asking when some function is smooth since in math it have two different meanings: for some it means strictly when the function is class $C^\infty$, for other when just is class $C^2$ or $C^1$, I would like to propose that when only the first derivatives are continuous it would be named as soft instead of smooth in order to avoid confussions... but I don't think it would be welcomed by everybody either

@Joako. Yes, it's unfortunate that smooth can mean just $C^1$ or as much as $C^\infty.$ The best is probably to be precise and write $C^1,$ $C^2,$ or $C^\infty.$

@md2perpe I did my try here but I got downvoted and closed as expected XD

When you raise your function to some power $p > 0$, you can "lift" the graph up or down and change the integral this way while still having $g(0) = 1$, i.e. consider instead
$$
g(x)^p =
\begin{cases} 
\exp(p \cdot (1-\frac{1}{1-x^2})) , & \text{if } |x| < 1 \\
0 , & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
with $p$ chosen such that $\int_{-1}^1 g(x)^p \,dx = 1$. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a closed formula to find the value of $p$ that does the trick. Solving for $p$ numerically gives me $p \approx 1.8995669372616584$.

I have used the $C_C^\infty$ function
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\sec^2(\pi x/2)&\text{for $|x|\lt1$}\\0&\text{for $|x|\ge1$}\end{array}\right.
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\sec^2(\pi x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac2\pi\int_{-1}^1e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\,\mathrm{d}\tan(\pi x/2)\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac4\pi u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{1b}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1c}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $\frac2\pi\,\mathrm{d}\tan(\pi x/2)=\sec^2(\pi x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(1b):}$ $u=\tan^2(\pi x/2)$
$\text{(1c):}$ $u=\frac\pi2t$

Vanishing of all derivatives at $\pmb{|x|=1}$
Note that the derivative of a polynomial in $\tan$ is another polynomial in $\tan$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan^n(\pi x/2)
&=n\pi/2\tan^{n-1}(\pi x/2)\sec^2(\pi x/2)\tag{2a}\\
&=n\pi/2\left(\tan^{n+1}(\pi x/2)+\tan^{n-1}(\pi x/2)\right)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}
&=-4e^{-4\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\tan(\pi x/2)\sec^2(\pi x/2)\tag{3a}\\
&=-4e^{-4\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\left(\tan^3(\pi x/2)+\tan(\pi x/2)\right)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, by induction, for some polynomial $P_n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\sec^2(\pi x/2)
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}\left(\tan^2(\pi x/2)+1\right)\\
&=e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}P_n(\tan(\pi x/2))\tag{4a}\\
\end{align}
$$
and for any polynomial $P_n$
$$
\lim_{|x|\to1^-}e^{-\frac4\pi\tan^2(\pi x/2)}P_n(\tan(\pi x/2))=0\tag5
$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{\left(x^2+1\right)\text{sech}^2\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}$ on $[-1,1]$.
This was found by constructing the anti-derivative $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\text{tanh}\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)$.

If you use instead $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\tanh\left(\frac{2x}{1-x^2}\right)\right),\ |x|<1;\ 0,\ |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ as the primitive function you end having a nice cummulative distribution function which pdf is given by your example.

You can do this simply by stitching together four cubic curves. Start with the segment of the curve $f(x)=1-4x^3$ on the interval $[0,\frac12]$:

Rotate this curve about the point $(\frac12,\frac12)$, by adding the segment of the curve $y=4(1-x)^3$ on the interval $(\frac12,1]$:

And reflect about the $y$-axis:

This has a continuous second (but not third) derivative, and by symmetry the area under the curve is $1$.

Thanks to Desmos for the pictures.

@Joako: I feel your pain! But the OP said "smooth and continuously differentiable", which doesn't make sense if their "smooth" implies $C^\infty$.

you are right, I am not making an argument, but instead, I made that mistake many times since as electrician the use of smooth is very wide, like when talking about filter envelope functions, so I try to rise awareness, I didn't know of the exitense of class $C_c^\infty$ functions untill accidentally they rise on one of my questions in MSE

Also consider this.
I expect the code is clear enough to adapt another
platforms.

Attending the comment, all we can see


P[t] doesn't fit some of OP's criteria. The area over $[-0.5,0.5]$ alone already looks to be quite close to $1$. Did you mean to use different parameters in the definitions of L/Q?

@user170231 well yes, playing with the parameters will be fun

A pretty simple one is $f(x) := (1 - x^2)^\alpha$ on $[-1, 1]$ and zero elsewhere, where $\alpha := 2.38175026...$, chosen to enforce the total integral constraint.

Same technique as @TonyK's answer, but using cubic smoothstep to avoid flatness near $x=0$. Also, packaged into one equation with absolute values:
$$ \operatorname{max}\left( 0,\operatorname{sign}\left( |x|-1 \right)\left( 
3x^2-2|x|^3-1 \right) \right) $$

